# JQuery & XML adjusting background

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following issue and I have no clue as in how to resolve this.

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```
<Item active="true" price="29.71" artnr="11123" group="fish"
      groupdescription="Fisch-Conv." headline="SeaWater
      src="images/test.png"
       />
```

basically I am needing to find the group vi a jQuery and if it is for instance "fish" then it will change the background image to another one.. and so fourth i.e. if there the group is "rods" then another image will be shown.. and if there is no group it should take the default background image which is in the body css.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: this is the beginning of the solution: `if ($('<Item active="true" price="29.71" artnr="11123" group="fish"
      groupdescription="Fisch-Conv." headline="SeaWater
      src="images/test.png"
       />').attr("group") == "fish")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Items>
        <Item active="true" price="29.71" artnr="11123" group="fish" groupdescription="Fisch-Conv." headline="SeaWater"  src="images/test.png"/>
        <Item active="true" price="29.71" artnr="11123" group="rods" groupdescription="Fisch-Conv." headline="SeaWater"  src="images/test.png"/>
        <Item active="true" price="29.71" artnr="11123" group="none" groupdescription="Fisch-Conv." headline="SeaWater"  src="images/test.png"/>
     </Items>
```

I'd store this in a string, then run parseXML() over it, which I'd push in a variable like this :

```
var xmlDoc= $.parseXML(myXmlString)
```

I could now this use this xmlDoc variable as a DOM object and traverse through it, if needed by passing it to $() as an argument.

```
$(xmlDoc)
```

Now, you could read up on `find(), closest()` etc and learn up on how you traverse in jQuery.

For example, if i want to get the `group` of the first `Item`, which lies in an `<Item>` section, I'd do this :

```
$("Items", xmlDoc).find("item")
```

Then, you'd collect this in an array and loop over it to set your bg :

```
var groups = $("Items", xmlDoc).find("Item").map(function () {
    return $(this).attr("group");
});
var $span = $("<span/>");

$.each(groups, function (i, group) {
    var $spanClone = $span.clone().attr("class", group).html("Class added :" + group + "</br>");
    $spanClone.appendTo("div");
});
```

That's it. Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/N3mYa/3/